# How can I avoid Ruby Perlisms in `gsub` and `match`?

Tags: ruby, regex, coding-style, global-variables

I'd like to avoid my method:

```
def page_cover
  return cover_title unless cover_title.match(/#{ capitalised_acronyms }/).present?
  cover_title.gsub(/#{ capitalised_acronyms }/, $&.upcase)
end
```

because it looks Perly, and I heard of [a news](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2251208&seqNum=3) that it might be deprecated in the future. From the book:

1. Prefer `String#match` to `String#=~`. The former returns all the match information in a `MatchData` object instead of several special global variables.
2. Use the longer, more descriptive global variable aliases as opposed to their short cryptic names (e.g., `$LOAD_PATH` instead of `$:`). Most of the longer names are only available after loading the English library.
3. Avoid methods that implicitly read from, or write to, the `$_` global variable (e.g., `Kernel#print`, `Regexp#~`, etc.).

I think I violated #3 in:

```
$&.upcase
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What is your question? Is it whether you should follow the advice in the article you cite? Your question does not in fact have anything to do with Perl. The influences on Ruby's development are many and varied. If you want to know if it's wise to make certain assumptions about where the language is going it doesn't really matter how we got to where we are now. Do keep in mind that the Ruby monks are very careful when they make changes to the language. The last thing they want is an angry mob outside their monastery.

Comment: I tried to edit your method down into a simpler example case, but then I realized I changed the meaning. You do know that `$&` is evaluated only one time, regardless of how many matches `gsub` encounters in the string? If you use `cover_title = "I love the nfl and nba"` and `capitalised_acronyms = "nba|nfl|mlb"`, your method will return `"I love the NFL and NFL"`. That seems like a bug.

Comment: Did you ever decide what to do here?

Answer (score 1):

While I neither agree nor disagree with a general principle of avoiding "Perlisms," I do agree that avoiding `$`+punctuation variables is a good way to improve the readability of your code.

There is no in-place substitute for `$&` (which holds the last regex match). You can, however, access the matched string using the `MatchData` object returned by `String#match`.

```
def page_cover
  if matchdata = cover_title.match(/#{capitalised_acronyms}/)
    cover_title.gsub(/#{capitalised_acronyms}/, matchdata[0].upcase)        
  else
    cover_title
  end
end
```

**NOTE**:

As written, this method (like your example method) will replace all matched lowercase acronyms with an uppercase version of *only* the first acronym matched: i.e. `"I love the nfl and nba"` becomes `"I love the NFL and NFL"`. If that is unintentional, there is a much simpler way to write this method:

```
def page_cover
  cover_title.gsub(/#{capitalised_acronyms}/, &:upcase)
end
```

This uses the `&` operator (which is completely unrelated to `$&`) to convert the symbol `:upcase` into the block `{|x| x.upcase }` behind the scenes.